# Javascript Array count and add result to variable

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var obj = {
    "people": [{
        "id": "100",
        "name": "name 1",
        "desc": "desc 1",
        "class": "a"
    }, {
        "id": "192",
        "name": "name 2",
        "desc": "desc 2",
        "class": "b"
    }, {
        "id": "324",
        "name": "name 3",
        "desc": "desc 3",
        "class": "b"
    }, {
        "id": "324",
        "name": "name 4",
        "desc": "desc 4",
        "class": "a"
    }, {
        "id": "324",
        "name": "name 5",
        "desc": "desc 5",
        "class": "a"
    }]
};
```

I know that for example, in order to get all the records with class "a" I do this:

```
obj.people.filter(function(item) { return item.class === "a" });
```

But How can I count to total number of records that contain class "a"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property from the returned array.

```
count = obj.people.filter(function(item) { return item.class === "a" }).length;
```

Or use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and add the comparison.

```
count = obj.people.reduce(function (r, item) { return r + +(item.class === "a") }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `length` of array returned by the `filter`

```
var result = obj.people.filter(function(item) { return item.class === "a" });
console.log( result.length );
```

or you can simply run a loop that tells you this count

```
var count = 0;
for( var counter = 0; counter < obj.people.length; counter++ )
{
   ( obj.people[ counter ].class === "a" ) && count++;
}
console.log( count );
```